# Beamer + TikZ: Get height of footline

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to draw a TikZ picture within a Beamer frame. In this picture, I want to place a node directly above the footline. Here is a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Luebeck}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pagetitle}
    text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[draw, anchor=south, yshift=\footheight] at (current page.south) {some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Omitting `yshift=\footheight` results in a frame where the footline is drawn above the node (because it touches the bottom of the frame). However, `\footheight` renders the node a little too height. Its south border does *not* touch the footline.

Is there an existing measure for the exact height of the footline?

Edit: With "measure" I mean a command that is able to get the height regardless of the used theme/fontsizes/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calculating the footheight, beamer adds an extra 4pt. You can reverse this to get the exact height of the footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Luebeck}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pagetitle}
    text
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \node[draw, anchor=south, yshift=\footheight-4pt] at (current page.south) {some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this results in the correct height for the MWE, it does not work in general for other themes. Do you know, if there is a more generic command?

Comment: @gerion Given that most build in beamer themes use this footline (or some variation of it) it should work for most themes distributed with beamer

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the `-4pt`. That answers my question.